# LMS Integration (Moodle) in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lti, lms

I want to integrate LMS in our application, as I am new to this. it would be great if some one share the knowledge of LMS architecture.

Likeour customer want to access our content via LMS/LTI how we can proceed and what key features we need to consider and what are the challenges.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a few years back for Canvas and here is what I remember.

You are the Tool Provider (TP) and those LMSes needs to show your content on their platform. The content can vary, from images, quizzes, etc. Canvas rendered our content in an iframe, and if I am not mistaken all are doing the same.

When some of your content is requested it is usually done via a LTI call. Here's an overview of the thing, https://www.imsglobal.org/basic-overview-how-lti-works - it's not complicated. Basically you need to have one endpoint where all the LTI calls land (they are called "launches"), validate them, and return a specific response.

I used this gem, https://github.com/instructure/ims-lti, and my code looked something like this:

```
    before_action :validate_launch, only: :launch

    def launch
      pp params.inspect
    end 
    
    private 

    def validate_launch
      @tool_provider = IMS::LTI::ToolProvider.new(consumer_key, secret_key, params)
      Lti::VerifyLaunchParameters.new(@tool_provider, consumer_key, params).call
      respond_with_error('Invalid LTI launch') unless @tool_provider.valid_request?(request)
    rescue Lti::InvalidLaunchParameter => exception
      respond_with_error(exception.message)
    end
```

Check out some youtube videos. I remember this guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0zhjzCxovw.

I really don't know how Moodle works, but Canvas had a demo playground where you could test those "launches".